# React/Node.js: Unable to delete an entry from frontend and database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database

So im currently learning react and trying to build a simple CRUD-Application. For that purpose i created a simple frontend, where you can type in a movie name and give a short review. The movie and review get stored in a database and are mapped on the frontend. As you can see i already added the movies "inception" and "disaster artist".

Now i want to be able do delete entrys from the frontend and my database. Thats why i implemented the delete button. Sadly whenever i try to delete something i get this error:
[image]

I have absolutely no idea what this mistake means and where its coming from.
I am really thankful for any advice because ive been looking at this for hours without figuring it out ^^
Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {


const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState('');
const [review, setReview] = useState('');
const [movieReviewList, setMovieReviewList] = useState([]);


useEffect(()=> {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response) => 
  {
   
    setMovieReviewList(response.data)
  })
});

const submitReview = () => {
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert', {
  movieName : movieName, movieReview : review}).then(() =>{ 
    
    //adds the new movie that we added to our databa to display it on the mapping
    setMovieReviewList([...movieReviewList, {movieName: movieName , movieReview: review} ])
  })
};
const deleteReview = (movie) => {
Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/api/delete/${movie}`);

}

  return (
    <div className="App">
           <h1>CRUD Application</h1>
            <div className = "form" >
                <label>Movie name : </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "movieName" onChange={(e) =>{
                  setMovieName(e.target.value)
                }}  ></input> 
                <label>Review : </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "review" onChange={(e) =>{
                  setReview(e.target.value)}} ></input>

                <button onClick={submitReview}> Submit</button>

                {movieReviewList.map((val)=>{
                    return <div className="card">
                      <h2>{val.movieName}</h2>
                      <p>{val.movieReview}</p>
                      <button onClick={()=> {deleteReview(val.movieName)}}>Delete</button>
                      <input type ="text" id = "updateInput"></input>
                      <button>Update Review</button>
                    
                    </div>
                })}
           </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password:"password",
  database:'CRUDDatabase',
});


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/api/get', (req,res)=>{

    const sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM CRUDDatabase.Movie_Reviews;'
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err,result)=> {
      res.send(result);
    })

})

//
app.post('/api/insert', (req,res)=>{
  const movieName = req.body.movieName;
  const movieReview = req.body.movieReview;

  const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO movie_reviews (movieName, movieReview) VALUES (?,?)'
  db.query(sqlInsert, [movieName, movieReview], (err, result) => {
    //console.log(result);
  });
})

app.delete("api/delete/:movieName"), (req,res)=>{
  const name = req.params.movieName;
  const sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM movie_reviews WHERE movieName = ?";

  db.query(sqlDelete, name, (err, result)=>{
   if (err) console.log(err);

  })

}

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("running on port 3001")
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welp i found it and it was just a simple syntax error:

in the backend instead of:

```
app.delete("api/delete/:movieName"), (req,res)=>{
  const name = req.params.movieName;
  const sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM movie_reviews WHERE movieName = ?";

  db.query(sqlDelete, name, (err, result)=>{
   if (err) console.log(err);

  })
```

its supposed to be:

```
app.delete("/api/delete/:movieName", (req,res)=>{
  const name = req.params.movieName;
  const sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM CRUDDatabase.Movie_Reviews WHERE movieName = ?";

  db.query(sqlDelete, name, (err, result)=>{
   if (err) console.log(err);

  });

})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the backend code, it looks like you're missing a slash in the endpoint.

Change from:

```
app.delete("api/delete/:movieName"), (req,res)=>{
```

To:

```
app.delete("/api/delete/:movieName"), (req,res)=>{
```

Comment: No that doesnt seem to be the error. I changed it buts still am getting the same error :(